# Clickable div except for links and buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

On my web app, I have a div that hides when clicked.  Then a new div (video) appears.  My problem is that I have an upvote button and a link in the first div, but if you click those, the div hides and pops up the video instead of the wanted functionality.

How can I have it so if they click the button or the link, it doesn't hide the first div and show the video?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
  $('.videoDiv').hide();
  $('.firstDiv').on('click', function () {
   $('.videoDiv').show();
   $('.firstDiv').hide();
  });
 });
</script>
```

First Div:

```
<div class="panel-body firstDiv">
  <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-md-7">
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" rel="nofollow" data-method="put" href="/startups/1/follow">Follow</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="btn-group-vertical pull-right" role="group">
      <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right upvote-btn" data-type="json" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="put" href="/startups/1/upvote">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Video Div:

```
<div class="panel-body videoDiv">
  <div class="video-js-box">
    <video id="" class=" video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="auto" height="auto" poster="" data-setup="{}">

    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could try increasing the z-index of the button and the link. Also you can handle the click event for the button and the link and stop its bubbling to its parent.

Comment: @user2756384 you like this http://jsfiddle.net/t2w4ux1p/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude events for link /upvote button that is, apply click function on `div` and check it is not on `.btn` only then execute your statements. Also, you need to check if target is not child of `.btn`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
    $('.videoDiv').hide();
    $('.firstDiv').on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$(".btn").is(e.target) //not clicked on .btn
          && $(".btn").has(e.target).length === 0) //clicked thing is not child of .btn
      {
        $('.videoDiv').show();
        $('.firstDiv').hide();
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, why do I need to make sure it is not a child of .btn?  For some reason my mind is going completely blank.

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.is()` , calling `.show()` , `.hide()` if `e.target` does not have `btn` `class`

```
$(function () {
  $(".videoDiv").hide();
  $(".firstDiv").on('click', function (e) {
   if (!$(e.target).is(".btn")) {
     $(".videoDiv").show();
     $(".firstDiv").hide();
   };
  });
});
```